# Como puedo obtener en un widget de filament, el registro actual para mostrar datos relacionados con este en la pagina de la vista

Tags: laravel-filament

Este es mi widget pero me dice que $record no esta definido

```
class TenantLandlordOverview extends BaseWidget
{
    public ?Model $record = null;

    protected function getCards(): array
    {
        return [
            Card::make('Organizaciones:', count($record->organizations)),
        ];
    }    
}
```